# Value of the String

Tags: java, string

I have just come across a string variable in my application code where the value is assigned as follows

```
    String YEAR="${year}";
```

What does the value of the String variable here?

Comment: Unless you have a preproccessor running over the code, it is what it says.

Comment: @MadProgrammer,Mr. Polywhirl: It will be ridiculous if I post without checking by Sysout what value it prints. I want to know exactly what the dollar value signifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being interpolated, just `${year}`.

I can almost guarantee that `String` is going to be interpolated elsewhere in the code.

Maven, for example, uses this syntax to inject variable values into it's configuration settings.

Comment: Does any tool other than Maven which analyses the behaviour differently.

Comment: Without more information from the code you're looking at, I won't be able to tell.

Comment: I have just known the build tool used for the Application is Maven. could you please explain me in detail how does variable values get injected into configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use an IDE such as IntelliJ and do a find usage on this variable. An extended find (search/find in path) may also yield results.
As others here have suggested, It is most likely being interpolated somewhere else.